# In C++ 11 Is there any way to branch by if a function parameter is compile-time constant or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, compile-time-constant

Is there anyway I can tell function argument is compile time-constant or not in C++ 11?. I would like to branch the functions body based on the results. For example, like below;

```
template <T>
size_t get_length(const T &t)
{
    return t.size();
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t get_length(const std::array<T, N> &t)
{
    return N;
}

// Maybe some template
??? foo(size_t length)
{
    ...
    // If length could be evaluated at compile time,
    return std::array<int, length>{};

    ...
    // Otherwise,
    return std::vector<int>(length);
}


// ??? and auto should be std::array if bar is std::array, std::vector if bar is std::vector or etc.
auto x = foo(get_length(bar));
```

I believe this need two task; First it should be able to determine if a value is compile time evaluable or not. Second, convert a value to compile time constant if possible.

Is there anyway one can do this? Or is there any reason this is impossible? It seems some say to use template function, but that forces caller to put compile time constant and not what I am looking for.

Comment: Something like `constexpr` and `std::enable_if` comes to mind.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I have managed to implement some what limited version with `std::conditional` but seeking better solution from betters :)

Comment: Would be nice to see a [mcve] containing your solution, and if you have a working solution already, it's probably better to ask at   https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: C++11 can't do this.  If you can update to C++20 you can use [`std::is_constant_evaluated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated)

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike It checks if the return value is used in a constexpr context, not if the arguments are constexpr.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `std::is_constant_evaluated` returns true if it is called in a constexpr context.  They show that on the cppreference in thier `constexpr double power(double b, int x)` example code

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike My point is, if I do `auto x = foo(42);`, I want the "compile-time value" branch to be taken, but `std::is_constant_evaluated` (and `if consteval`) return false here. Being forced to make the variable `constexpr` severely limits the usefulness of what OP wants to do. One needs a compiler extension for this, such as `__builtin_constant_p`.

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike 
Unfortunately because this is potentially for embedded project, C++ 20 is not available :(

Comment: Do you want specifically a branch or would a function overload suffice? The later should be considerably easier.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev I want whatever kind of compile time branching including std::enable_if or specialization, overloading or even considerably certain optimization to keep api of `foo` uniform.

Comment: If you already have `bar` objects, then why not simply skip the step of getting the length at all? You could have separate `foo` overloads accepting arrays or vectors to achieve the same even easier: `foo(bar);`. Sure, only covers this specific part, not catches up with any other function returning a size, but it's a starting point at least...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is reasonably possible by changing `get_length` to return an `integral_constant`:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t N>
auto get_length(const std::array<T, N> &t)
{
    return std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>();
}
```

Then, to use the result,

```cpp
auto foo(auto length) {
    // If length could be evaluated at compile time,
    if constexpr (requires { typename std::array<int, length>; })
        return std::array<int, length>{};
    // Otherwise,
    else
        return std::vector<int>(length);
}
```

This uses facilities from C++14 through C++20 (terse templates, `if constexpr`, concepts) but it should be straightforward to backport to C++11 if required.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I don't really get the point. You put the () at the end of returning clause. Isn't it just return regular size_t?

Comment: It works fine in GCC and MSVC, but not in Clang, where `foo()` creates `vector` instead of `array`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/shh7Whn4f

Comment: @HenriqueBucher It somewhat does, since `std::integral_constant` could be used with runtime value in some context. I did get some result with `std::integral_constant` with C++ 11. Will update the question after a bit more test,,,

Comment: @lighthouse the `()` creates a `std::integral_constant` object by value-initialization; an extra pair of parentheses `()()` would call it to return a `size_t`. You could also use `{}` - this is mainly a matter of style.

Comment: @Fedor interesting, I wonder if this is related to https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2280r4.html? There's a fairly simple workaround which is to use `decltype(length)::value` in the concept check: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6caMh5od8

Answer (score 2):

Not strictly in C++11 as per the language but most mainstream C++ compilers do accept the builtin `__builtin_constant_p` function to indicate if the value is constant or not.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template < typename T >
inline void print( T x ) {
    if ( __builtin_constant_p(x) ) {
        std::cout << "Constant:" << x << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Variable:" << x << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    const int a = 1;

    // It's in a variable but it's a constant in the context
    print( x );
    // Constant without a doubt
    print( a );
    // Some compilers will consider the calls below constant 
    // after loop-unrolling them into 1..2..3 constants
    for ( int j=0; j<3; ++j ) {
        print(j);
    }
}
```

Produces:

```bash
Program stdout
Constant:1
Constant:1
Variable:0
Variable:1
Variable:2
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/KaxWd6xcn

Beware though that what some compilers consider a "constant" others will not consider.

Clang 14+ will consider the variables in the loop as constant while gcc and clang <14 will not. GCC 4.6.4 will consider all variables.

So not sure how useful this will be as it is somewhat "subjective".

Comment: MSVC doesn't have `__builtin_constant_p`.

Comment: Does "most mainstream C++ compilers" mean GNU-compatible compilers?..